# Sanity studio custom component view - Get fields from referenced document

Tags: sanity

I am new to Sanity, and have been blown away by how good the studio is. However, there is something I cannot manage to do! I am trying to create a custom view for a document (so we can preview how the document will look before publishing it), and I cannot find how to access the fields from a referenced document.

So, this is my case.

I have a "figure" document, where I can upload images with captions, etc. Then, I have a "campaignBanner" document, where I create a banner to display on my website. In this "campaignBanner" document, I am adding a "figure" document as part of its schema. This is the schema for "figure":

```
export default defineType({
  name: 'figure',
  title: 'Figure',
  type: 'document',
  fields: [
    defineField({
      name: 'title',
      title: 'Title',
      type: 'string',
    }),
    defineField({
      name: 'image',
      title: 'Image',
      type: 'image',
      options: {
        hotspot: true,
      },
    }),
    defineField({
      name: 'caption',
      title: 'Caption',
      type: 'string',
    }),
  ],
});
```

And this is the schema for "campaignBanner":

```
export default defineType({
  name: 'campaignBanner',
  title: 'Campaign Banner',
  type: 'document',
  fields: [
    defineField({
      name: 'title',
      title: 'Title',
      type: 'string',
    }),
    defineField({
      name: 'bodyText',
      title: 'Body Text',
      type: 'string',
    }),
    defineField({
      name: 'image',
      title: 'Image',
      type: 'reference',
      to: [{ type: 'figure' }],
    }),
    defineField({
      name: 'callToAction',
      title: 'Call To Action',
      type: 'callToAction',
    }),
  ],
});
```

I am creating a custom view for my "campaignBanner" document using `defaultDocumentNodeResolver`, but when trying to get the `image` from my figure, I only get its `id` and `type`. I am following this guide: https://www.sanity.io/docs/create-custom-document-views-with-structure-builder

```
JSON Data for Sammenlign med leasing!
{
  "_createdAt": "2023-03-13T08:18:52Z",
  "_id": "edd79002-b7da-4038-b062-0a6cfc318acd",
  "_rev": "9NHEjaGRyhTuuOJfx6SLGa",
  "_type": "campaignBanner",
  "_updatedAt": "2023-03-13T10:42:44Z",
  "bodyText": "Amazing body text!",
  "callToAction": {
    "_type": "callToAction",
    "text": "text",
    "url": "/url"
  },
  "image": {
    "_ref": "d227e079-ea99-43f0-8bc4-40e20cf8c7e9",
    "_type": "reference"
  },
  "title": "A title"
}
```

Is it possible to expand my `image` reference to be able to get the asset and display it in my custom view?

Thanks!

Alejandro

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to edit your `image` field definition within `campaignBanner` like so:

```
defineField({
  name: 'image',
  title: 'Image',
  type: 'figure'
})
```

If you want to keep your reference in place as you have it above, instead of having that data live in the `campaignBanner` document, you can use a [GROQ query to expand the reference](https://www.sanity.io/docs/how-queries-work#db43dfd18d7d).